# Twitter Oauth for android works on Browser but not on Twitter App

Tags: android, twitter, oauth, callback, twitter-oauth

Hi i have to do a twitter Oauth for my app.
I've done it using this:

CALLBACK_URL="twitter://twitterTraficoCCS?"

Manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".TwitterLogin"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:host="twitterTraficoCCS" android:scheme="twitter" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Now.. In the Code

```
String authUrl = httpOauthprovider.retrieveRequestToken(httpOauthConsumer, mActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.TwitterCallBackUrl));
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
```

With:

```
httpOauthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(TwitterConsumerKey, TwitterConsumerSecret));
        httpOauthprovider = new DefaultOAuthProvider("http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token", "http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
```

This work like a charm on the browser/chrome but when i select the TwitterApp form the Action Menu it goes to the twitter app, ask for authentication of the my app. I select ok, it says, redirecting back...and never calls back my app.

Any sugestions?

Thanks in Advance.

EDIT:
By "Twitter app its not making a callback" i mean, its not calling my onNewIntent()

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994905/browser-callbacks-and-android-activity-stack-madness/12984202#12984202 for comment on doing this in a webview, where you'd catch that URL in your WebViewClient. You then have more control over the activity stack too.

Answer (score 0):

Change the activity's launch mode to singleTask in your manifest.

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

That did the trick for me. Hope it helps :)